# Python: Comparison between a 1D and a 2D array, asking where both arrays have nonzero entries

Tags: python, numpy

Consider two arrays, `array1` and `array2`, where `array1` is 1D and `array2` is 2D:

```
array1 =  [  0    0  -80 -60    0 -30 ... ] 

array2 = [[-50    0  -20   0  -70 -80 ...], 
          [  0    0    0 -70  -40   0 ...],
          [  0  -50  -30 -60    0   0 ...],
           ...                        ]
```

Here is what I want to achieve: I want to compare `array1` with each row of `array2`. Whenever both `array1` and the respective row of `array2` have entries that are nonzero, I want to increment a counter. In the end, I want to have an array, whose entries correspond to the counters value for every comparison.

Take the array from above as an example: The output would be:

```
[ 2, 1, 2 ]
```

I hope that is clear.

Now, here is the tricky part: I do not want to use any for-loops. I want to achieve this using numpy-methods only!

I started working on this, but I am a bit lost. Nevertheless, here are some of my ideas:

```
indices1 = array1.nonzero() 
indices2 = array2.nonzero()
equal_entries = np.where(np.equal(indices1, indices2))
```

Assuming that both `array1` and `array2` are 1D, this will return a numpy-array, whose entries give the indices where both arrays have nonzero elements. That's what I want. Almost. Only, I want the length of this array. And - as `array2` is 2D - I want this length for every comparison between `array1` and each row of `array2`. It might be, that `equal_entries = np.where(np.equal(indices1, indices2))` works fine, even if `array2` is 2D. So, this line might return a 2D numpy-array, where each row gives the elements where `array1` and the respective row of `array2` both have nonzero elements. Not sure though. But even, if it does, I am left with finding the number of elements in each row of the result without using a for-loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array != 0` to get an array like `[False, False, True, True, False, True, ...]` for array1.

You do that for both arrays and use `&` to only get `True` where both arrays are zero.

Then you take the row-wise sum.

```
np.sum((array1 != 0) & (array2 != 0), axis=1)
```

If it is not intuitive that array1 and array2 compare themselves using rows and not columns of array2 (e.g. if array2 is quadratic), you can explicitly shape array1 as a row-vector:

```
np.sum((array1[np.newaxis, :] != 0) & (array2 != 0), axis=1)
```

General notes:

- If you want numpy to count something, generate a boolean array and count the `True` entries using `np.sum()`.
- If you want to perform a reducing operation (like sum) row- or column-wise, use the `axis` parameter: You give it the axis you want to reduce, so if you want the sum per row (axis 0), you want to reduce along all columns (axis 1), you use `np.sum(..., axis=1)`.

Comment: hey, great answer! ... since I want the nonzero entries, does that mean I only need to change `array1 == 0` to `array1 != 0`, or does this logic comparison (for whatever reason) only work with `== `

Comment: Sure. I changed the answer accordingly.